# ssrs - repeat tablix at top of every page

Tags: reporting-services, header, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a report made up of 2 tablix.
The first tablix just has some basic information in it, and is linked to a dataset.

The second tablix is linked to a different dataset and is made up of a lot of rows and spans multiple pages.

All I am looking to do is have the first tablix be displayed at the top of every page.

I cant add it to a header because you can't add a tablix containing data to a header.
I also don't want to just repeat column headers, because I need the entire tablix repeated.

Comment: Can you show what is your first tablix look like. Is it just one row? If its one row you use use First function.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your Tablix is set up you could do the following:

• Select Tablix Properties and check column Headers > Repeat Header  columns on each page In the grouping pane in advanced mode (click on small black down arrow on far right of grouping pane); select the corresponding (static) item in the row group hierarchy.
• In the   properties grid, set RepeatOnNewPage to true and Keep with Group to After